# Giving failed to load pdf files in postman when send pdf from aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I am failed to download pdf files giving me this[postman giving me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvOCy.png) when it giving me base64 if i upload it on other website like base64 to pdf converter then it give me my pdf but postman failed to load pdf file.why? and what is the solution of this?

i try to return this
let response = {

```
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
    'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
  },
  body: pdf.toString('base64'),
  isBase64Encoded: true
};
console.log(response)

return response;
```

also i enable proxy interation and add binary media type as application/pdf but now working (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmgPM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing at least problems and I made these settings in postman.

[image]

Comment: tysm its working